# Javascript dialog nonsense

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a button on my page that will display a dialog asking for text and another button (to submit the information to email) `onClick`.  I cannot get the dialog to show.  I adapted an existing example on jsFiddle that displays the dialog `onCreate`; however, I need the dialog to be displayed when I click a button.

So here it is:[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3d7QC/1943/)

I believe the problem lies in the function call.

```
<p><a href="#dialog-message" onclick="showDialog();">Question</a></p>
```

This is the start of my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My title &middot; stuff</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <style>
           .containerx {
        background-color: #1abc9c;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: bottom right;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        }    
        .imag{
        padding-left:10px;
        padding-top:10px;
        }        
    </style>


     <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
<script src="js/flatui-checkbox.js"></script>
<script src="js/flatui-radio.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="js/application.js"></script>   

<script>
  function showDialog(){
     $("#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: ['center', 'center'],
        show: 'blind',
        hide: 'blind',
        width: 400,
        dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
        buttons: {
            "Send question": function() {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
             }
        }
     });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Works fine if you choose the right loading method in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3d7QC/1951/

Comment: I did that and it works. However, if I do that in my real page. It does not work. I mean, I added the script in the HEAD section and it does not work. even if in fiddle it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You just forgot to include jquery UI :)

Comment: Without seeing your page it's hard to tell. Checked your browser's console for errors?

Comment: I attached for you the start of the page (HEAD section) in the body of the question. Please look at it.

Comment: Also, the console says: `jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function` Seems like jQuery is not loaded ?!?!

Comment: You probably need to load jQuery UI before your script. In fact, you might as well put your script all the way at the end.

Comment: I did that. As it is reflected in the body of the question above (I edited the question). Still nothing showing and the same error in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select No wrap option in jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/3d7QC/1952/) otherwise `showDialog` is local function to that scope (in which jsFiddle puts it).

In case of your own page - don't forget to include jquery-ui.

Comment: I included jquery in the HEAD, just before the function, and still no success. I added in the question above the HEAD section so you can see

Comment: Please review my HEAD section above, and tell me what am I doing wrong? To me it looks like I DO include the jquery-ui...

Comment: The problem was in my local jquery script as it appears. I replaced it with an online CDN and now it works. Thank you all for your time. Your answer was the first that talked about including jQuery-ui, and even if it was included in the first place, although it was not working correctly) still, the problem was from that line of code. So your answer is the one I accept

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that jQuery UI is not loaded when the function is run. You'll need to move the jQuery UI script to be right after jQuery.

While you're at it, you could load the rest of your scripts before the inline one as well.

Comment: I did that, still not working. (I changed in the question body too)

Comment: The problem was in my local jquery script as it appears. I replaced it with an online CDN and now it works. Thank you all for your time. I will accept the first question that spoke about loading jquery